# Ms Word save to Web Functionality in the Office 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, ms-word

I want to write a code in c# for adding save to web(custom url) for saving word documents, for this microsoft has explained some registry editing here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff709802%28v=office.14%29.aspx

first thing i want to know is, i am not able to know where these files would be saved after editing registry, means where is the url i am giving to save files, i have edited registry directly without any code, i am able to see save to gmail option,in ms word, but not able to sign in, so what went wrong with me in that

second thing i want to know, how to create web service for the saving word document, i am totally new to web service.

if anyone can help me with the code of web service and explaining the details of first question, please help
thank you